# The practice of deep clone failed

Tags: java, object

I tried to make a deep clone via overridong the clone method, but the result is not how a deep clone behaves(`blanks` and `oldBlanks` should print differently).

It is supposed to print:

```
192, []
1_2, [1]
```

It actually prints:

```
192, []
192, []
```

An MCVE is presented.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Program {

static class Blank implements Cloneable {

    @Override
    protected Blank clone()  {

        Blank b = new Blank(this);

        return b;

    }

    public Blank(String str) {
        origin = str;
        uradix = str.length();

        String strn = str.replaceAll("_","0");
        existed = Integer.parseInt(strn);


        for (int i = 0; i < uradix; i++) {

            int radix = uradix - i;

            if (str.charAt(i) == '_'){
                not_existed.add(radix-1);
            }

        }

    }

    public Blank(Blank b){
        this.origin = b.origin;
        this.uradix = b.uradix;
        this.existed = b.existed;

        for (Integer i :
                b.not_existed) {
            int k = i;
            this.not_existed.add(k);
        }
    }

    String origin;
    int uradix;
    int existed;
    ArrayList<Integer> not_existed = new ArrayList<>();//remain sequence: ->, i.e. left to right
}

static Blank[] copy(Blank[] ts){

    for (Blank t :
            ts) {
        t = t.clone();
    }

    return ts;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Blank[] blanks = {new Blank("1_2"),new Blank("_2"),new Blank("_2_")};
    Blank[] oldBlanks = copy(blanks);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(blanks[0].origin);

    System.out.println("before the change");
    System.out.println(blanks[0].origin+", "+blanks[0].not_existed);
    System.out.println(oldBlanks[0].origin+", "+oldBlanks[0].not_existed);

    int index = 1;
    sb.replace(index,index+1,"9");
    blanks[0] = new Blank(sb.toString());

    System.out.println("after the change");
    System.out.println(blanks[0].origin+", "+blanks[0].not_existed);
    System.out.println(oldBlanks[0].origin+", "+oldBlanks[0].not_existed);
}
```

}

p.s. My tutor said that a static class used in such a pattern is weird, but that should not be the problem because the problem reproduces even if I modify the class `Blank` outside non-static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your `clone` method that causes the problem, bBut rather the way you implemented your `copy`.
You return the original Blank[] reference and then adapt it.

If you do this:

```
static Blank[] copy(Blank[] ts){
    Blank[] ts_copy = new Blank[ts.length];
    for (int i=0; i<ts.length; i++) {
        ts_copy[i] = ts[i].clone();
    }
    return ts_copy;
}
```

Then I get an output like this:

> before the change
>   1_2, [1]
>   1_2, [1]
>   after the change
>   192, []
>   1_2, [1]

Comment: It is confused to me. Shouldn't the original blanks be modified after the method being executed?